# Prove inequality: $\frac13\left(x^3+y^3+z^3\right)\ge xyz+\frac34|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|$

Tags: inequality

> For any nonnegative numbers $x,y,z$ prove inequality:
> $$\frac13\left(x^3+y^3+z^3\right)\ge xyz+\frac34|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|$$

#### My work so far:

I used formulas

1. $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$
2. $x^2+y^2+z^2\ge xy+yz+zx$
3. AM-GM

Comment: Oh sure. I made a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 1, it is sufficient to prove $(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)\geqslant \frac{9}{4}|(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)|$. Without lost of generality, we can assume $x\geqslant y\geqslant z\geqslant 0$, and  $a=x-y, b=y-z$, so $a+b=x-z$.

Note that $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx=\frac{1}{2}(x^2-2xy+y^2+y^2-2yz+z^2+z^2-2zx+x^2)=\frac{1}{2}((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(x-z)^2)=\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2)$.

Now, it is reduced to prove $\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2)\geqslant \frac{9}{4}ab(a+b)$. This follows from

$\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)(a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2)\geqslant \frac{1}{2}(x-z)(a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2)=\frac{1}{2}(a+b)(2a^2+2b^2+2ab)\geqslant \frac{1}{2}(a+b)6ab\geqslant \frac{9}{4}ab(a+b),$ where we have used $a^2+b^2\geqslant 2ab$.

And the equality holds when $a=b=0$, i.e. $x=y=z$.